# EmberJS: retrieving model from route when multiple models are retrieved

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a route that has two models associated with it as shown below:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        sites: this.store.find('site'),
        songs: this.store.find('song')
    })
  },
```

Now later on, I need to be able to retrieve the first object in the `sites` model in order to do a transition I'll show below. I figured I can set the models using `setupController`, but when dealing with multiple models as depicated above, I'm not sure how to fill this part in:

```
  setupController: function(controller, ???) {
    controller.set('model1', ???);
    controller.set('model2', ???);
  }
```

And finally, I'd like to be able to retrieve the first object in model1 (it's multiple instances of `site` as described above)

```
afterModel: function() {
    firstRecord = this.('sites').objectAt(0);
    this.transitionTo('site', firstRecord.id);
  }
```

It's also possible that I'm not designing my application properly. `sites` in this case is a component I built that displays different sites within a few different controllers. The controllers are dependent on this component in that they need to know which site is selected in order to do their own thing. So in controllers that need access to the component, I do something like:

```
{{site-nav sites=sites}}
```

Where `site-nav` is my component. It needs its own model, as does the controller itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're going to need to modify your model hook slightly, to make sure you stay in the right scope:

```
model:function(){
    var self = this;
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        sites: self.store.find('site'),
        songs: self.store.find('song')
    })
}
```

To get the different models in `setupController`, you just access it from the second parameters, like this:

```
setupController:function(controller,models) {
    controller.set('sites',models.sites);
    controller.set('songs',models.songs);
}
```

`afterModel` provides two parameters, this first being the resolved model for your route, so you'd do it something like this:

```
afterModel:function(models){
    var site = models.sites.get('firstObject');
    this.transitionTo('site',site);
}
```

Comment: I believe I'm passing a null object to transitionTo() here. Tried your solution and see this in ember console: Error while loading route: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Try logging it to the console and seeing what you get.

Comment: yep - tried this.    console.log("model: " + models.get('sites').get('firstObject')); Doesn't come up with anything.

Comment: Basically `models.get('sites')` is undefined when invoked in afterModel()

Comment: Try `console.log(models.sites)`.

Comment: I think you're RSVP isn't actually working because `this` is referring to the RSVP and not the route.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Everything seems to work just fine now as long as you change `models.get('sites').get('firstObject')` to `models.sites.get('firstObject')`, the aforementioned syntax doesn't work, get an undefined.